# How to remove an element from DynamoDB instantly?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

TTL is disabled
[image: ttl disabled]

After deletion appears `_delete` and `_ttl` but the element itself does not disappear
[image: after deletion appears _delete and _ttl but the element itself does not disappear]

How to remove an element from DynamoDB instantly?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not enabling or disabling TTL
It was necessary to do the editing api

- amplify update api
- Enable conflict detection? N

this will remove items instantly, and also solve this error

errorType: "ConflictUnhandled"
message: "Conflict resolver rejects mutation."